# Is there a fast way of updating a set of keys in a nested dictionary with a specific value?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a help dictionary where the key is a nested tuple of an event pair and features, the number of features can be between 1 - N. related to the event pair. The value is the support of said event pair and features.

I have a dictionary `d` which is a nested dictionary where the support of each event pair and every possible partial duplicate of the feature will be stored.

This is done in the following code snippet

```
  help_d = {(('Event 1', 'Event 2'),('Feature A', 'Feature B',...,'Feature T', 'Feature H')) : 10,
            (('Event 1', 'Event 3'),('Feature C', 'Feature E',...,'Feature H', 'Feature G')) : 50,
            (('Event 1', 'Event 4'),('Feature F', 'Feature G',...,'Feature T', 'Feature X')) : 100,
             .....
            (('Event 10', 'Event 15'),('Feature D', 'Feature E',....,'Feature V', 'Feature B')) : 5}


 d = defaultdict(int,defaultdict())
 
 for key,value in help_d.items():
     event_a = key[0][0]
     event_b = key[0][1]
     feature_tuple = key[1]
     
     #Every possible partial duplicate of the features
     all_keys_to_update = list(itertools.product(*zip(feature_tuple, itertools.repeat(''))))

     #Nested for loop that takes around 3-4 secs per iteration
     for key_to_update in all_keys_to_update:
         d[(event_a,event_b)][key_to_update] += value
```

The size of `help_dict` is around 12 000 keys.

The size of the list `all_keys_to_update` is around 10 000.

The nested for loop takes around 3-4 seconds to loop through, which means that ***it will take around 11 hours to finish this particular code snippet***.

***Example where I only have 3 events and 2 features***

```
help_d = {(('Event 1', 'Event 2'),('Feature A', 'Feature B')) : 10,
         (('Event 1', 'Event 2'),('Feature A', 'Feature C')) : 20,
         (('Event 1', 'Event 3'),('Feature D', 'Feature C')) : 50,
         (('Event 2', 'Event 3'),('Feature D', 'Feature B')) : 10}
```

Which would result in the following dictionary `d`

```
    d = {('Event 1','Event 2'): {('','') : 30,
                                 ('A','') : 30,
                                 ('','B') : 10,
                                 ('','C') : 20,
                                 ('A','B') : 10,
                                 ('A','C') : 20},
          ('Event 1','Event 3'): {('','') : 50,
                                 ('D','') : 50,
                                 ('','C') : 50,
                                 ('D','C') : 50},
          ('Event 2','Event 3'): {('','') : 10,
                                 ('D','') : 10,
                                 ('','B') : 10,
                                 ('D','B') : 10}}
```

***Is there a faster way of updating a set of keys in a nested dictionary with the same value?***

Comment: Can you edit your question and put there expected output?

Comment: It sounds like you want mutable keys, which can sort of be done, but is best avoided.

You're likely better off using something other than a Python dict or Python defaultdict.  If you really think you need mutable keys, you could try adding a level of indirection, like have your tuples point at other single-element lists that are updated en masse.

Comment: @AndrejKesely I edited with a simple example, note that in reality I will have more than 3 events and more than 2 features per event pair, but the logic would be the same regardless.

Comment: @user1277476 Could you specify some more details? What other options could there be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could save roughly 30% of the time (depending on the data) by reducing the number of indexations but I don't see how you could make that much faster given the sheer number of combinations you are generating:

```
d = defaultdict(lambda:defaultdict(int))
for (events,features),count in help_d.items():
    counts = d[events]
    for combo in product(*zip(features, repeat(''))):
        counts[combo] += count
```

However, depending on how you use this dictionary afterwards, it may be more efficient to only generate the counts upon use. You could achieve that by creating a class or a function that implements "on demand" calculations for a given event and feature combination.

```
help_events = defaultdict(list) # list of feature patterns for each event pair
for (event,features),count in help_d.items():
    help_events[event].append(features)

help_cache = dict() # cached results  
def getFeatureCount(events,pattern):
    # check cache first
    if (events,pattern) in help_cache:
        return help_cache[(events,pattern)]

    # compute total of matching feature patterns
    result   = 0
    for eventFeatures in help_events[events]:
        if all(e==f or f=="" for e,f in zip(eventFeatures,pattern)):
            result += help_d[(events,eventFeatures)]

    #save to cache and return result
    help_cache[(events,pattern)] = result
    return result
```

usage:

```
getFeatureCount(('Event 1', 'Event 2'),('Feature A', '')) # --> 30

# wich is equivalent to d[(('Event 1', 'Event 2'),('Feature A', ''))]
```